# Python utilizing split lists

Tags: python, list, if-statement, split, tuples

How can i utilize the second part of a list in Python?

For example, the list contains a string and integer:

```
('helloWorld', 20)
('byeWorld', 10)
('helloagainWorld', 100)
```

I wish to create an if statement on the second part (integer) of the list, preferably without creating a new list to store the integers. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just use index

```
>>> a = ('helloWorld', 20)
>>> a[1]
20
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use indexing:

```
>>> a = (1,2)
>>> a[0]
1
>>> a[1]
2
```

Answer (score 1):

you can either use a function to get the second element of the `tuple` or use something like [`operator.itemgetter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter), here is the example given in that documentation:

```
>>> inventory = [('apple', 3), ('banana', 2), ('pear', 5), ('orange', 1)]
>>> getcount = itemgetter(1)
>>> map(getcount, inventory)
[3, 2, 5, 1]
>>> sorted(inventory, key=getcount)
[('orange', 1), ('banana', 2), ('apple', 3), ('pear', 5)]
```